# Not all CSS formatting is being loaded by JSP

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm working on a J2ee web project and in my JSP. CSS is being inconsistent when I deploy my application and I check out the front-end. I load the CSS file using

```
<style>
    <%@include file="/css/indexCSS.css"%>
</style>
```

and also I've used

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/indexCSS.css"/>
```

The thing is, both of these work, but not completely, and are very inconsistent and finicky. For example, I will change something on my CSS, save, and republish the server, and deploy my application, and it doesn't show the change. A lot of the CSS is being displayed, but not all of it. Sometimes it works for some reason a couple days later even if I didn't change some of the CSS code. Does anyone know why the code I'm using to load CSS is finicky?

Comment: Try refreshing the browser after clearing the browser cache.

Comment: You could also use a cache busting trick, like adding a query string to the path (for example: `/indexCSS.css?v=1.0` which you change every time you deploy (or use a random number so you don't have to manually change it).

Answer (score 0):

`<%@include file="file.jsp"%>` is a **static** include, so it keeps in your server's temp folder until you delete it.

When you want to update your page using `<link>` tag use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> instead.

Answer (score 0):

use the jstl tags.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/css/indexCSS.css"/>"/>
```